# Is correct to apply the next boolean algebra rule?

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

Im trying to simplify the next boolean term
\$E(A\bar{B}+C\bar{E})+\bar{E}(\bar{A}B+\bar{C}E)\$
in this way

\$A\bar{B}E+CE\bar{E}+\bar{A}B\bar{E}+\bar{C}E\bar{E}\$

\$A\bar{B}E+\bar{A}B\bar{E}\$

But in this last line I don't know if this can be argumented as the same case of \$A+\bar{A}=1\$,so finally it can be minimized
\$A\bar{B}E+\bar{A}B\bar{E}=1\$

Comment: Your derived equations 2 and 9 are the same. And **No** that is not equal to 1.

Comment: This happens me a lot, I get back to the start.

Comment: Your expression was simplest when you just had \$A\bar B E + \bar A B \bar E\$; why did you even re-introduce  \$C\$? You should have been happy that you eliminated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is not correct.

Not for any special case or exception, but for the very simple reason that the negation of the terms has been carried out improperly.

\$ \overline{A\bar{B}E} = \bar{A} + B + \bar{E} \$

Which is clearly not the same thing as:

\$ \bar{A}B\bar{E} \$

But I simply don’t understand these questions. Verifying the result is much easier and faster than typing the question in MathJax.

Just write down the 8-row truth table for the expression. If it is = 1 it would be rather obvious from there. You would see that it’s not, even before you write the second row down.